# Validation isee in dropdown columns of rhandontable module of R

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am using this module (rhandsontable) in one of my projects and it is great (saved me from a lot of time consuming operations). I am stuck at validation issue with dropdown. Here is what I did:

```
rhandsontable(my_data_frame,contextMenu=FALSE,stretchH='all',fixedColumnsLeft = 1,fixedRowsTop = 1) %>% hot_col(
      col = "Domain", type = "dropdown", source = domain_list)
```

The problem is that if I select the FIRST option from the dropdown list, it is accepted, but if I select the second option or third option or any other option except first, it is highlighted in red background.

[image: As you can see, first option is considered as VALID but others are considered Invalid]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason after struggling with it for many hours and trying many things. In this process, I learnt the whole documentation of handontable.

The issue was that my domain list was having items starting with a SPACE ( ) and handsontable removes the space while presenting the dropdownlist. The first item did not have any space, so it is VALID, second item onwards had starting with space so it was flagged as INVALID.

I trimmed the space in the list before passing it to rhandontable and now it is perfect.